# How to impliment assertion on total avg value of each script rather than each thread in JMeter?

Tags: jenkins, automation, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

Which assertion has to be use to check latency,throughput,received & sent bytes and error rate ?How to impliment assertion in total avg value of each script in JMeter to automate?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter per se doesn't provide this functionality so you can go for one of the following approaches:

1. [AutoStop Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-autostop-listener-how-to-do-it-right) is capable of automatically stopping the test if one of the following metrics exceeds defined thresholds:

   - Response Time
   - Latency
   - Error Rate
2. If you are running your test in [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) you can use [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin)  to mark build as failed or unstable basing on various metrics

   [image: Jenkins Performance Plugin]
3. And finally you can run your JMeter test via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) having very powerful and flexible [pass/fail criteria subsystem](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) so if there will be a clash between expected and actual metrics it will basically return non-zero exit code which you can use in shell scripts or Jenkins freestyle jobs and/or pipelines.